# How to fix Error with alchemy-web3 - Webpack < 5

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, web3js

*interact.js*

```
require('dotenv').config();
const alchemyKey = process.env.REACT_APP_ALCHEMY_KEY;
import { createAlchemyWeb3 } from "@alch/alchemy-web3";
const web3 = createAlchemyWeb3(alchemyKey);

const contractABI = require('../contract-abi.json')
const contractAddress = "My_Contract_address";

export const mintNFT = async(url, name, description) => {
    //error handling
    if (url.trim() === "" || (name.trim() === "" || description.trim() === "")) { 
      return {
       success: false,
       status: "❗Please make sure all fields are completed before minting.",
      }
     }
     const tokenURI = "ipfs://My_URI"
     window.contract = await new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);

    //set up your Ethereum transaction
    const transactionParameters = {
        to: contractAddress, // Required except during contract publications.
        from: window.ethereum.selectedAddress, // must match user's active address.
        'data': window.contract.methods.mintPublic(window.ethereum.selectedAddress, tokenURI).encodeABI()//make call to NFT smart contract 
    };

    //sign the transaction via Metamask
    try {
    const txHash = await window.ethereum
        .request({
            method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
            params: [transactionParameters],
        });
    return {
        success: true,
        status: "✅ Check out your transaction on Etherscan: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/" + txHash
    }
    } catch (error) {
    return {
        success: false,
        status: " Something went wrong: " + error.message
    }

    }
   }

export const connectWallet = async () => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      try {
        const addressArray = await window.ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_requestAccounts",
        });
        const obj = {
          status: " Write a message in the text-field above.",
          address: addressArray[0],
        };
        return obj;
      } catch (err) {
        return {
          address: "",
          status: " " + err.message,
        };
      }
    } else {
      return {
        address: "",
        status: (
          <span>
            <p>
              {" "}
              {" "}
              <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href={`https://metamask.io/download.html`}>
                You must install Metamask, a virtual Ethereum wallet, in your
                browser.
              </a>
            </p>
          </span>
        ),
      };
    }
  };

  export const getCurrentWalletConnected = async () => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      try {
        const addressArray = await window.ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_accounts",
        });
        if (addressArray.length > 0) {
          return {
            address: addressArray[0],
            status: " Write a message in the text-field above.",
          };
        } else {
          return {
            address: "",
            status: " Connect to Metamask using the top right button.",
          };
        }
      } catch (err) {
        return {
          address: "",
          status: " " + err.message,
        };
      }
    } else {
      return {
        address: "",
        status: (
          <span>
            <p>
              {" "}
              {" "}
              <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href={`https://metamask.io/download.html`}>
                You must install Metamask, a virtual Ethereum wallet, in your
                browser.
              </a>
            </p>
          </span>
        ),
      };
    }
  };
```

I am trying to connect alchemy into my front end react native website. But am getting this error:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/@alch/alchemy-web3/node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 7:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/keyesbruh/Documents/Programming/nft-project/node_modules/@alch/alchemy-web3/node_modules/eth-lib/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/@alch/alchemy-web3/node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js 31:74-91

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/keyesbruh/Documents/Programming/nft-project/node_modules/@alch/alchemy-web3/node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/@alch/alchemy-web3/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 30:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/keyesbruh/Documents/Programming/nft-project/node_modules/@alch/alchemy-web3/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/@alch/alchemy-web3/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 32:12-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/Users/keyesbruh/Documents/Programming/nft-project/node_modules/@alch/alchemy-web3/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/assert/assert.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/keyesbruh/Documents/Programming/nft-project/node_modules/assert/assert.js'


ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 3:16-43

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/keyesbruh/Documents/Programming/nft-project/node_modules/cipher-base'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 24:11-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/keyesbruh/Documents/Programming/nft-project/node_modules/dotenv/lib'


ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 26:13-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/keyesbruh/Documents/Programming/nft-project/node_modules/dotenv/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 28:11-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/Users/keyesbruh/Documents/Programming/nft-project/node_modules/dotenv/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 9:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/keyesbruh/Documents/Programming/nft-project/node_modules/eth-lib/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 37:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/keyesbruh/Documents/Programming/nft-project/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 39:12-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/Users/keyesbruh/Documents/Programming/nft-project/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 41:9-22

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/Users/keyesbruh/Documents/Programming/nft-project/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
```

I solved this error before in the following thread: [ERROR: Webpack < 5 after installing web3 and implementing into React Native App.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71245845/error-webpack-5-after-installing-web3-and-implementing-into-react-native-app)

But that was by importing web3 a different way. This alchemy I am unsure if there is any other way to import it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this issue recently. From my research, I found that it is a known issue with Webpack. I was using react-scripts version 5.0.0. The simplest solution for me was to use an earlier version of react-scripts in my project, delete my node_modules directory and re-run `npm install`.

```
// package.json
{
  ...normal package.json attributes
  "dependencies": {
    ...other dependencies,
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  }
}
```